# Can we use dynamic values in static json file

Tags: json

Am having a json file for application configuration like below.

```
[
  {
    "name": "environment",
    "value": "prod"
  },
  {
    "name": "deployment_date",
    "value": "2022-12-21"
  }
]
```

The variable deployment_date, I want it as dynamic to current UTC date. Can we use any programing language to achieve this? something like getUTCDate().toString() instead "2022-12-21"?

Answer (score 0):

Using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```bash
jq '(.[] | select(.name == "deployment_date")).value |= (now | todate)' file.json
```

**Output**

```json
[
  {
    "name": "environment",
    "value": "prod"
  },
  {
    "name": "deployment_date",
    "value": "2022-12-21T12:46:11Z"
  }
]
```

---

```bash
jq '(.[] | select(.name == "deployment_date")).value |= (now | strflocaltime("%Y-%m-%d"))' file.json
```

**Output**

```json
[
  {
    "name": "environment",
    "value": "prod"
  },
  {
    "name": "deployment_date",
    "value": "2022-12-21"
  }
]
```